# GWT -> Jetty very slow loading first time after a while

Tags: gwt, deployment, webserver, jetty, war

I am playing around with deploying GWT app to a remote Jetty web server. I have created GWTs default sample project and haven't added anything. So it is extremely lightweight application right now.

This how I proceed. I create a war file out of war directory, I copy the war file and paste it in this remote Jetty web server.

Everything is working fine, but not if I wait for example 1 hour and do refresh on browser. It takes at least 30 seconds to page be loaded. It is not like I change the code or copy-paste the war file again in Jetty. I don't do anything. If I wait for more then an hour and do refresh then it takes at least 30 seconds to load this page, but 1 or 5 minutes after the first load, the page is loaded immediately.

Maybe there is configuration in GWT or Jetty which has to be changed or??? Do you have any idea what cause this delay on loading the page after a time of inactivity?

Comment: Strange. I created a remote Tomcat web server to see if I have the same kind of delay as in Jetty. I pasted the same war file under Tomcat webapps and experience the same problem. If I don't refresh the sample web page for a while, like 1 hour, then reloading the page takes at least 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure or Heroku to deploy to, you get a single container called "dyno". Dyno sleeps after an hour. You have to add several dynos and change conf to avoid sleeping. That is what I have understood after reading some docs. I hope I am right.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the dyno to go to sleep (idle) I have create a node module that every x mins make a request to your heroku app.
Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/raytracer1975/herokuKeepAlive)